# How to count and return the objects related to a table to a model field

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'd like to know how to count the number of Students related to a certain ClassRoom, and to place the current quantity to a field so whenever I add a student to a ClassRoom I can know the current number of students in it.

```
  class Student(models.Model):
        ClassRoom = models.ForeignKey(ClassRoom)


    class ClassRoom(models.Mode):
       qtt_current_students =
```

------------Edit ------------------

I tried the following, but the  qtt_current_students doesn't get the 
instance.ClassRoom.student_set.count()

Whenever I add an Student the field doesn't udate

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=Student)
def Student_pre_save(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.ClassRoom.qtt_current_students = instance.ClassRoom.student_set.count()
```

Comment: You wouldn't do this in a field. You'd query it when you need it, either with `.count()` or via annotations.

Comment: Note that if you do something like this, then the number of students will not reflect the actual relations if it is changed. It would just hold the number of students at the time of creation. Is that what you want? Also, @DanielRoseman is correct ^

Comment: No, I wanted it to be real-time, as soon as I add one student, the other table would know and count it, But as I can't do it, How I can count the current number at least ?

Comment: @OptimusCrime I misunderstood you, If the users were removed from the classroom, I would like to see the current number in the field as well.

Comment: you could use a signal to do that, like when a student is added after post.save it will update the classroom student column, then you can get the latest number of student in that field, but you need to normally declare the classroom model

Comment: @Exprator I tried to do what you said, but it didn't work, check my edit pls.

Comment: @Goun2 added an answer try once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this, and it worked great.

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Student)
def student_post_save(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    t = ClassRoom.objects.get(pk=instance.ClassRoom.pk)
    t.qtt_current_students = instance.ClassRoom.student_set.count()
    t.save()

@receiver(post_delete, sender=Student)
def student_post_delete(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    t = ClassRoom.objects.get(pk=instance.ClassRoom.pk)
    t.qtt_current_students = instance.ClassRoom.student_set.count()
    t.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Student)
def Student_pre_save(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    ClassRoom.qtt_current_students = instance.ClassRoom.student_set.count()
```

try this,

Comment: Your answer didn't work, but your idea was fundamental so I could find the solution, thanks.